# to reboot or not upon switching "Enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP"?

Tags: windows, networking

Should I restart computer upon enabling/disabling "NetBIOS over TCP/IP" on my NIC TCP/IP properties

Windows XP SP3

Control Panel --> Network Connections --> right-click on connection, choose Properties  ---> tab General ---> Internet Protocol (TCP/IP), btn Properties ---> btn "Advanced" --> tab WINS --> section "NETBIOS setting"

Comment: Since you are not prompted to restart, one would assume No is the answer, but hey its Windows, I would not hurt to reboot anyway.

Comment: Too true +1 <short>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy questions if to have network working.

There is no need  to reboot PC.

It is not necessary even to restart NIC